# Importing s3 Bucket in Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation

In a Cloudformation template, I define two S3 Buckets.

```
 Bucket1:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
   ...
 Bucket2:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
   ...

Outputs:
 Bucket1:
  Description: S3 Bucket
  Value: !Ref Bucket1
  Export:
   Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}:Bucket1"
 Bucket2:
  Description: S3 Bucket
  Value: !Ref Bucket2
  Export:
   Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}:Bucket2"
```

I use these exported buckets in two different cloudformation templates.

**Template 1**

```
Parameters:
 LoaderCodeBucket:
  Type: String

Resources:
 MyLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
   Code:
    S3Bucket:
     Fn::ImportValue:
      !Sub "${LoaderCodeBucket}:Bucket1"
```

**Template 2**

```
Parameters:
 ProcessorCodeBucket:
  Type: String

Resources:
 MyOtherLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
   Code:
    S3Bucket:
     Fn::ImportValue:
      !Sub "${ProcessorCodeBucket}:Bucket2"
```

Template 1 passes `aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body ...` while Template 2 fails due to

**Template error: the attribute in Fn::ImportValue must not depend on any resources, imported values, or Fn::GetAZs**.

The only difference is the lambda function in template 2 is used in an aws analytics application that is also defined in template 2.

I know for sure it's the S3 Bucket causing issues because when I remove that section of code, it passes the validation check.

I have been using this site to try to debug this issue, but none of the questions seem to answer this particular issue.

This is in same region/same account.

My question is:
Why is this particular section of code (template 2) throwing a template error when template 1 passes with no error?

Comment: Where does `ProcessorCodeBucket` get assigned? The difference is likely in how `ProcessorCodeBucket` is populated vs how `LoaderCodeBucket` is populated

Comment: What do you mean how it gets assigned?

The buckets are populated from an external repo that uploads zip file of the code that is in the external repo. Both buckets are populated from the same external repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example.

Template 1:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Test"
Resources:
  MyBucketOne:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    Properties:
      BucketName: bucket-one-12341234
  MyBucketTwo:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    Properties:
      BucketName: bucket-two-12341234
Outputs:
  MyBucketOneOutput:
    Description: "Bucket Name of BucketOne"
    Value: !Ref MyBucketOne
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-BucketOne"
  MyBucketTwoOutput:
    Description: "Bucket Name of BucketTwo"
    Value: !Ref MyBucketTwo
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-BucketTwo"
```

Template 2: we can import it as `!ImportValue my-s3-BucketOne`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Test"
Resources:
  MyLambda:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      FunctionName: "test-s3-import"
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !ImportValue my-s3-BucketOne
        S3Key: "index.zip"
      Description: "Test Lambda"
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 60
      Role: test-role-arn
```

If you do want to use from Parameter, it will be `Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${BucketExportNamePrefix}-BucketOne`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Test"
Parameters:
  BucketExportNamePrefix:
    Type: String
    Default: "my-s3"

Resources:
  MyLambda:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      FunctionName: "test-s3-import"
      Code:
        S3Bucket:
          Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${BucketExportNamePrefix}-BucketOne
        S3Key: "index.zip"
      Description: "Test Lambda"
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 60
      Role: test-role-arn
```